# Black window when opening CellProfiler

Tags: image-processing, installation

I installed [CellProfiler](http://cellprofiler.org/) version 3.0.0 from [here](http://cellprofiler.org/previous_releases/), but when I open it, I only get a black window instead of the application's main page. Any idea why?

I am using windows, and my machine in 64bit.

*Note: I posted a question on image.sc forum but got no replies. Your help is appreciated!*

[image]

Comment: There is not enough information to replicate the issue. What OS, version numbers, other software do you have? Did you follow the installation instructions? Where did you get the installation files from? Etc. Etc. Etc.

Comment: Edited the question. What do you mean by "other software do you have"?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question from someone in our labs, so I installed it on my machine to see if it was the same.  I got the black window as well, but after a wait of about 30 seconds there was a few lines of text visible and the program launched shortly after.

Comment: What happened in those 30 seconds?